# approximating essential supremum

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ be a filtred probability space. For $t\in [0,T]$, we are given sets $U_t$ of non negative stochastic processes $X=\{X_s;0\le s\le T\}$. We know that for $s\le t$ we have $U_t\subset U_s$. Let $f$ be a positive r.v. in $\mathcal{F}_T$, which is fixed. Now the object I study is the following:

$$W_t:=\operatorname{ess}\sup_{X\in U_t}E[X_T f|\mathcal{F}_t]$$

I was able to prove that $\{E[X_T f|\mathcal{F}_t]:X\in U_t\}$ is upward directed. Hence I know that there is a sequence $\{X^n\}$ in $U_t$ such that

$$W_t=\lim_n E[X_T^n f|\mathcal{F}_t]$$

where the limit is increasing. I want to prove that $(W_t)$ has the supermartingale property. Using monotone convergence

$$E[W_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=\lim_nE[fX_T^n|\mathcal{F}_s]$$

My notes says, because $\{X^n\}\in U_t\subset U_s$, we have

$$\lim_nE[fX_T^n|\mathcal{F}_s]\le \operatorname{ess}\sup_{X\in U_s}E[fX_T|\mathcal{F}_s]=W_s$$

Why is this inequality true? This is bothering me now for a while, but I really do not see why it is true. So some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $Z_T$ in the inequality required is a typo and should be $X_T$. If it is so :

$E[f X_T^n | \mathcal{F}_s]  \leq \operatorname{ess}\sup_{X \in U_t} E[f X_T|\mathcal{F}_s] \leq \operatorname{ess}\sup_{X \in U_s} E[f X_T|\mathcal{F}_s]  $

The last inequality is true because the set $U_s$ on which we are maximizing is bigger than $U_t$ and hence the given inequality is true. Hope this helps!